# Maximum value for hub.lease_seconds in PubSubHubbub

Tags: publish-subscribe, websub

I have been using PubSubHubbub version 0.4 to retrieve YouTube realtime data. I was going through the [PubSubHubbub document](https://pubsubhubbub.github.io/PubSubHubbub/pubsubhubbub-core-0.4.html) to know about ***hub.lease_seconds***

In this document, they didn't mention anything about maximum limit for this parameter.

What is the maximum value that can be given as hub.lease_seconds parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's 828000 seconds. If you try to give any value larger than 828000 it is simply ignoring it and sets the hub.lease_seconds as 828000.

Answer (score 0):

It has been increased to *864000* (10 days)

Comment: Please elaborate when, which occasion, why, by whom ... this was increased.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).