# What are the limitations when working with PubSubHubbub (youtube API)?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, webhooks, websub

I've been able to implement the functionality and everything works fine with the test data. My concerns are with the limitations and possible problems with tracking more users. My questions are:

- How many users are we allowed to track?
- I've found that the max value for `hub.lease_seconds` is 828000 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64754986/maximum-value-for-hub-lease-seconds-in-pubsubhubbub) and am wondering if this essentially means that I have to renew that every (say) 9 days?
- Any other limitations one should be concerned of?

I couldn't find information about this online so even pointing me in the direction of some docs would be highly appreciated!